# jQuery.get method is not working as expected

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have an array in javascript method. I want to access that on a separate php file. I am trying jQuery.get method. Here is the code:

```
<script>
function Quantity(){
    var count = document.getElementById('hidden').value;
    alert(count);
    var Quantity=new Array();
    var i=0;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
       Quantity[i]=document.getElementById(i).value;
    }
    document.getElementById('hdnQuantityArray').value = Quantity;
    jQuery.get("CalculateTotal.php", Quantity);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

I am using a hidden field `hdnQuantityArray` to send this array through GET. The problem is, this code is not redirecting me to the file `CalculateTotal.php`. Instead it remains on the same page with the URL containing hidden field's value.

Please guide me if I am doing something wrong here. Suggest me an alternate otherwise.

Comment: `jQuery.get()` is not for page redirecting, for loading data via AJAX.

Comment: What?! `Quantity` is an array AND a function?

Comment: Can this create a problem? I dont think so. I am using it and it's working fine. At least this is not the issue.

Comment: @asma that it not syntactically/semantically possible a function can return array but hoe can it assume two role of being a function and still be an array

Comment: @asma, yes, that can definitely be part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

not sure that it will work...

replace

```
jQuery.get("CalculateTotal.php", Quantity);
```

with

```
location.href="CalculateTotal.php?Quantity"+$(Quantity).serializeArray()
```

Comment: This is also not redirecting to the form `CalculateTotal.php`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to that page you just need:

```
window.location = "CalculateTotal.php";
```

jQuery.get is for retrieving that page as a string. So you could retrieve it and then use it in your page in some content area like:

```
var totalContent = jQuery.get("CalculateTotal.php", Quantity);
$('#some_content_div').html(totalContent);
```